# How to find out the maximum length of a dimension in a ragged dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.dataset

If I have the following dataset built from a ragged tensor, how can I get the maximum length (4 in this example) of all elements?

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    tf.ragged.constant([[1, 2, 3, 4], [], [5, 6, 7], [8], []]))
```

Comment: I assume you mean without iterating over the whole dataset? If not you could use something like `max([len(i) for i in iter(ds)])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the function [`reduce`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#reduce):

```
ds.reduce(0, lambda state, value: tf.math.maximum(state, len(value))).numpy()
```